# How to install OpenModelica 1.9.5 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: installation, ubuntu-20.04, openmodelica

I installed the latest version on OpenModelica (version 1.16.5) on Ubuntu 20.04.
However, this version has problems with the packages (examples).

So, by recommendation, I'm trying to install version 1.9.5 or 1.10.X, without success.
Since I'm a novice Linux user, I don't know how to do this.

On the site,

"https://openmodelica.org/download/download-linux"

for older versions, it is suggested to use the line

"deb [https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/linux/releases/1.xx.x/"](https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/linux/releases/1.xx.x/%22).

I honestly do not know how to do it and that is why I ask for help to be able to carry out this procedure.

Grateful.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Ubuntu 20.04 (focal), you can only install OpenModelica versions released after April 2020 (because we don't update the old releases for newer OpenModelica versions). The oldest you can install without using docker or compiling your own OpenModelica is the following as `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list`:

`deb https://build.openmodelica.org/omc/builds/linux/releases/1.16.0/ focal release`

Which example does not work in the latest OpenModelica for you? We have done some fairly extensive testing and the change from the old to the new frontend is a net gain in the number of models that simulate.

Comment: Virtually all examples that don't work have some form of error. I tested on Windows too and the same thing occurs.

Comment: It would probably do some good if you report the errors, then.

Comment: Hi. So. It will not be possible to forward the prints with the error messages because when trying to re-install the current version and the installation does not complete by displaying the error below. This occurred when I installed Scilab through the terminal. I'm sorry.

Comment: :~$ for deb in deb deb-src; do echo "$deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt `lsb_release -cs` stable"; done | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/openmodelica.list
deb http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal stable
deb-src http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal stable

:~$ wget -q http://build.openmodelica.org/apt/openmodelica.asc -O- | sudo apt-key add -
OK

Comment: :~$ apt-key fingerprint
/etc/apt/trusted.gpg
--------------------
pub   rsa2048 2012-09-10 [SCEA] [expires: 2024-09-08]
      AEEB 94E9 C5A3 B54E CFA4  A66A A684 470C ACCA F35C
uid           [ unknown] Insynchq Inc <services@insynchq.com>

pub   rsa2048 2010-06-22 [SC]
      D229 AF1C E5AE D74E 5F59  DF30 3A59 B536 6497 0947
uid           [ unknown] OpenModelica Build System <build@openmodelica.org>
sub   rsa2048 2010-06-22 [E]

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------

Comment: pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      790B C727 7767 219C 42C8  6F93 3B4F E6AC C0B2 1F32
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2012) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2012-cdimage.gpg
------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2012-05-11 [SC]
      8439 38DF 228D 22F7 B374  2BC0 D94A A3F0 EFE2 1092
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu CD Image Automatic Signing Key (2012) <cdimage@ubuntu.com>

/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ubuntu-keyring-2018-archive.gpg
------------------------------------------------------

Comment: ------------------------------------------------------
pub   rsa4096 2018-09-17 [SC]
      F6EC B376 2474 EDA9 D21B  7022 8719 20D1 991B C93C
uid           [ unknown] Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key (2018) <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

Comment: :~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Hit:2 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:3 http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:4 http://apt.insync.io/ubuntu focal InRelease                              
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease               
Ign:6 http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal InRelease
Hit:7 http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal Release

Comment: Get:9 http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal/stable Sources [47,1 kB]
Get:10 http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal/stable i386 Packages [19,0 kB]
Get:11 http://build.openmodelica.org/apt focal/stable amd64 Packages [23,2 kB]
Fetched 89,3 kB in 12s (7.543 B/s)                          
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
16 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.

Comment: :~$ sudo apt install openmodelica
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

Comment: The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 openmodelica : Depends: omedit (< 20000) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: Try `apt remove omc-common` before trying to install an older omc.

Answer (score -1):

Now this error occurs after installing Scilab through the terminal.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @Fabrio Cardoso. The answer you provided to your own question doesn't seem to be helpful.
Your question about how to install OpenModelica 1.9.5 on Ubuntu Focal is already answered by sjoelund: It's not possible.

But please open a ticket on https://trac.openmodelica.org/OpenModelica/newticket and give a working minimal example to show us an example that doesn't work with 1.16.5 but did in older versions. There we can search for the error in more detail and if there is a regression we'll try to fix it.